# SDK Nikon C with JNA

Tags: java, c, sdk, java-native-interface, jna

I'm working on a wrap between a Nikon SDK written in C and a Java program with JNA libruary.

All the process ended in a EntryPoint (MAIDEntryPoint) that is inside a dll.
The signature of this EntryPoint in C is:

```
SLONG CallMAIDEntryPoint( 
    LPNkMAIDObject  pObject,    // module, source, item, or data object
    ULONG       ulCommand,  // Command, one of eNkMAIDCommand
    ULONG       ulParam,        // parameter for the command
    ULONG       ulDataType, // Data type, one of eNkMAIDDataType
    NKPARAM         data,           // Pointer or long integer
    LPNKFUNC    pfnComplete,    // Completion function, may be NULL
    NKREF       refComplete )   // Value passed to pfnComplete
```

The `LPNkMAIDObject pObject` is a struct defined in C as:

```
typedef struct tagNkMAIDObject
{
    ULONG   ulType;         // One of eNkMAIDObjectType
    ULONG   ulID;
    NKREF   refClient;
    NKREF   refModule;
} NkMAIDObject, FAR* LPNkMAIDObject;
```

the value I'm interesting on is the `NKPARAM data` that is this next struct:

```
//stEnum Struct

typedef struct tagNkMAIDEnum
{
    ULONG       ulType;         // one of eNkMAIDArrayType
    ULONG       ulElements;     // total number of elements
    ULONG       ulValue;        // current index
    ULONG       ulDefault;      // default index
    SWORD       wPhysicalBytes;         // bytes per element
    LPVOID  pData;              // allocated by the client
} NkMAIDEnum, FAR* LPNkMAIDEnum;
```

and the scope of the EntryPoint is to populate the argument `LPVOID pData`.
The `pData` argument is a pointer that is allocate in this way:

```
NkMAIDEnum stEnum;
stEnum.pData = malloc(stEnum.ulElements * stEnum.wPhysicalBytes);
```

what I done is to "translate" whit jna the struct and the EntryPoint, that are this:

```
//EntryPoint
int MAIDEntryPoint(NkMAIDObject pObject,
                   int kNkMAIDCommand_capGetArray,
                   int ulCapID,
                   int kNkMAIDDataType_enumPtr,
                   NkMAIDEnum nkMAIDEnum,
                   Object o,
                   int i);
```

And the Struct will be defined as a Java Class:

```
@Structure.FieldOrder({"ulType","ulID","refClient","refModule"})
public class NkMAIDObject extends Structure {

    public NativeLong ulType;   // One of eNkMAIDObjectType
    public NativeLong ulID;
    public TagRefObj.ByReference refClient;
    //public Pointer refClient;
    public Pointer refModule;
}
```

```
@Structure.FieldOrder({"ulType", "ulElements", "ulValue", "ulDefault", "wPhysicalBytes", "pData"})
public class NkMAIDEnum extends Structure {
    public NativeLong ulType;
    public NativeLong ulElements;
    public NativeLong ulValue;
    public NativeLong ulDefault;
    public short wPhysicalBytes;
    public Pointer pData;
}
```

At this point I initializa the `Pointer pData` as:

```
NkMAIDEnum nkMAIDEnum = new NkMAIDEnum ();
nkMAIDEnum.pData = new Memory(nkMAIDEnum.ulElements.longValue()*nkMAIDEnum.wPhysicalBytes);

nResult = INSTANCE.MAIDEntryPoint(
                   pRefMod.pObject,                
                   kNkMAIDCommand_CapGetArray,     
                   ulCapID,                        
                   kNkMAIDDataType_EnumPtr,        
                   nkMAIDEnum,                     
                   null,
                   0);
```

And then pass it to the EntryPoint, but I receive an Invalid Access Memory .
I think the problem is how to initialize the pData in the Java-JNA part or also what kind of data should be the pData in the class NkMAIDEnum

For instance, I don't care about the other EntryPoint's parameter because they're right, and alto the parameters `nkMAIDEnum.ulElements` and `nkMAIDEnum.wPhysicalBytes` are number not equals to 0 or null, they are respectively `nkMAIDEnum.ulElements = 1` and `nkMAIDEnum.wPhysicalBytes =  4` they are initialize in a previously EntryPoint, that is exactly the same as the one written here but instade of initialize the `pData`, it initialize the `nkMAIDEnum.ulElements` and `nkMAIDEnum.wPhysicalBytes`.

Please help me to understan where I'm wrong, I'm stuck

Answer (score 1):

I see three possible problems:

1. JNA needs enough type information to be able to allocate the correct number of bytes in structures (for memory allocation) or method/function signatures (for the stack).

   Your use of `Object` to map the 6th argument in `MAIDEntryPoint()` is most certainly wrong.  JNA has no way to know how many bytes that takes. Since that argument is actually `LPNKFUNC pfnComplete` it looks like a `Pointer` would be the correct mapping for it.
2. Another possibility is if you've incorrectly mapped (or allocated) the `NkMAIDObject` type that is the first argument to `MAIDEntryPoint()`.  You haven't shown us the mapping, but it could very well be an incorrect allocation.
3. Finally you indicate the native allocation is done with  `malloc(stEnum.ulElements * stEnum.wPhysicalBytes)` and state

> the parameters `nkMAIDEnum.ulElements` and `nkMAIDEnum.wPhysicalBytes` are number not equals to 0 or null.

- However, you don't show where these are assigned.  You simply define a new structure with `new NkMAIDEnum()` and do not assign any values to `.ulElements` or `.wPhysicalBytes` so they are, in fact, initialized to zero.  (Unless you have code you aren't showing us.)

Comment: Hi! I added a specification, if you need more I will try to add it, but is very difficult because there is a lot of code XD.
For you point 1. I will try to specify a type of pfnComplete, but is a null value, so I don't know if it's important

Comment: @SilviaFrancia It's probably a pointer but JNA/Native needs to know that it's 8 bytes of 0's.